# Issue with Spring ServletRegistrationBean on official example

Tags: spring, spring-boot

There are the following lines in the example of Spring-ws spring guide

```
MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
ServletRegistrationBean  bean  = new ServletRegistrationBean();

return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
```

I get the following error

```
The constructor ServletRegistrationBean(MessageDispatcherServlet, String) is undefined
```

How can I fix this error?. What version of Spring boot I have to use?

****EDITED

This is the pom.xml. I think it's the same than the guide. I work with Eclipse.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-producing-web-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- tag::springws[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::springws[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!-- tag::xsd[] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- end::xsd[] -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Java class

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;

@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig  extends WsConfigurerAdapter{


        public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
            servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
            servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
            ServletRegistrationBean  bean  = new ServletRegistrationBean();

            return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");


        }
```

Do I have to add dependencies to the pom.xml. What is the dependency wher is ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");

Comment: With Spring boot 2.0.5 it's working well. please take a look this example in this link: https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/ and let me know if this helps you :)

Comment: This is the guide that I follow

Comment: It's weird, because it's working well.. perhaps you added some dependency more and clashed, could you please share your code? so I can reproduce that error :) .

Comment: I edited my pom.xml and my java class

Comment: Cool :)  have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MetricsServlet needs to implement `javax.servlet.Servlet` dependency. You need to have this class in your project/classpath. To do this, declare this maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Glad I could help